# Is there a fortune-mod about security?

Tags: terminal

Do you know if a `fortune-mod` about security exist?

Comment: Since the fortune-mod isec on sourceforge present by @steve is not enough from what I am standind for I have decided to write one. First version works https://github.com/aurelien-git/fortune-mod-security

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a `fortune-mod` does indeed exist.

[fortune-mod-sec on sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fortune-mod-sec/)

Comment: I will try it now and told you back if it correspond to what I am looking for. Thanks for your help

Comment: Since this one is not enough ... I have decided to write my own :-)